# WinRT: Own event handler, token won´t be removed

Tags: c#, events, windows-runtime

I created a class for custom events in WinRT.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BA_Lib
{
    public class RTEventHandler<T>
    {
        private EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>> m_EventTokenTable = null;

        public event EventHandler<T> Event
        {
            add { EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>>.GetOrCreateEventRegistrationTokenTable(ref m_EventTokenTable).AddEventHandler(value); return; }
            remove { EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>>.GetOrCreateEventRegistrationTokenTable(ref m_EventTokenTable).RemoveEventHandler(value); }
        }

        public void Fire(T argument)
        {
            EventHandler<T> temp = EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>>.GetOrCreateEventRegistrationTokenTable(ref m_EventTokenTable).InvocationList;
            if (temp != null)
                temp(null, argument);
        }

        public void Fire(object sender,T argument)
        {
            EventHandler<T> temp = EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>>.GetOrCreateEventRegistrationTokenTable(ref m_EventTokenTable).InvocationList;
            if (temp != null)
                temp(sender, argument);
        }
    }
}
```

I use this class to create custom bindings to own events, like this:

```
public RTEventHandler<int> Count{get;set;}

public void init(){Count=new RTEventHandler<int>();}
```

and then from other classes:

```
EventHolder.Count.Event+=myEventHandler;
```

This works like a charm, but when I try tu unregister from the event with `EventHolder.Count.Event-=myEventHandler;` the token stays is the table. This leads to unwanted behaviour, as the event handler accumulates and are fired multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue and will post my final solution for further reference.

The problem was, that the RemoveEventHandler function expects a token an not the handler. This token is returned by the AddEventHandler function. Because add returnes void I was not able to pass this token back. I have added a dictionary to hold this tokns and link them to the EventHandler.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BA_Lib
{
    public class RTEventHandler<T>
    {
        private EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>> m_EventTokenTable = null;
        Dictionary<EventHandler<T>, EventRegistrationToken> _tokens = new Dictionary<EventHandler<T>, EventRegistrationToken>();

        public event EventHandler<T> Event
        {
            add
            {
                if (_tokens.ContainsKey(value))
                    return;
                var token = EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>>.GetOrCreateEventRegistrationTokenTable(ref m_EventTokenTable).AddEventHandler(value);
                _tokens.Add(value, token);
                return;
            }
            remove
            {
                if (_tokens.ContainsKey(value))
                {
                    var token = _tokens[value];
                    EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>>.GetOrCreateEventRegistrationTokenTable(ref m_EventTokenTable).RemoveEventHandler(token);
                    _tokens.Remove(value);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Fire(T argument)
        {
            EventHandler<T> temp = EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>>.GetOrCreateEventRegistrationTokenTable(ref m_EventTokenTable).InvocationList;
            if (temp != null)
                temp(null, argument);
        }

        public void Fire(object sender, T argument)
        {
            EventHandler<T> temp = EventRegistrationTokenTable<EventHandler<T>>.GetOrCreateEventRegistrationTokenTable(ref m_EventTokenTable).InvocationList;
            if (temp != null)
                temp(sender, argument);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing is keeping track of the connection between a token and the EventHanlder (the function to call). This way I am able to resolve the token from the function and remove the entry.